# Parent/Child class ownership semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, class-design

I've been building a system with a parent object, where it creates various child objects, and each child object requires a master object to function. Now, so far, I've been creating `shared_ptr<Parent>` and `Child*`, so when the creator of Parent *and* all the Childs are gone, the Parent goes too.

But I'm re-designing my API so that Child can be created on the stack (previously it was just the heap). Now I'm unsure about what to do with Parents, as I don't see why they shouldn't also be creatable on the stack- in terms of their actual function- but what happens if Parent is destroyed and then someone tries to use a Child that they moved, copied, or allocated on the heap? Should I just throw an exception? Skip performing the operation? Or just stick to allocating Parents on the heap?

Comment: Using std::weak_ptr<> and std::shared_ptr<> together seems like it would help simplify your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem sentence

> if Parent is destroyed and then someone tries to use a Child ...

If this is possible then you have shared ownership, which implies creation on the heap.

So, either you stick to heap allocation or drop the shared ownership semantics. There is no other way. `weak_ptr` is merely away of *advertising* the state of a shared object.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do what you're advertising:

> if Parent is destroyed and then someone tries to use a Child ...

This is going to cause a problem as @spraff mentioned.

The way to achieve what you are saying is to also make the Child a shared_ptr and allow a shared ownership between the Parent and also whatever else is trying to use the child...